# Swagger UI Response Example Asp.Net Core Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swagger-net

I'm using Swagger.AspNetCore to document my api. So far i was happy to use xml comments to generate response model examples until i reach the point when i've got to document embeded object.
 So i have simple model:

```
public class SummaryResult
{
    /// <summary>Total Cost.</summary>
    /// <value>Total Cost.</value>
    /// <example>6433.2</example>
    public double TotalCost { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Owner.</summary>
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }
}

public class Owner
{
    /// <summary>Owner Name.</summary>
    /// <value>Owner Name.</value>
    /// <example>Michael</example>
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And Swagger UI document it only for TotalCost, Owner property just skipped whatever i do. Does anyone have a clue why this can happen? And how to fix it.
I know how to deal with List - just put on top xml comment like `<list></list>` but it's not my case.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it shows fine on my end:
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index#/ActionFilter/ActionFilter_Get

Here is how that looks like on the model tab:

[image: 1]

As you can see in the image it does show the summary and the example value.

Here is the code:
https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/blob/master/Swagger_Test/Controllers/ActionFilterController.cs#L29

Educated guess there could be something else removing those elements.